# How to use DSC Script Configuration to configure FCI

Tags: azure, powershell-dsc

How can I use DSC script part to cOnfigure a failover cluster and join the node to that cluster. Any links will be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant add node to Existing cluster using DSC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323721/cant-add-node-to-existing-cluster-using-dsc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DSC Module that should help you.
[SqlServerDsc Module](https://github.com/PowerShell/SqlServerDsc/tree/dev/Examples/Resources/SqlSetup)

The page I have linked to has some examples of configuring a cluster.